# How to handle array with laravel requests?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using the simple form and array input like this (not dynamic)

```
<input type="text" name="pre_ref_position[]" id="pre_ref_position">
<input type="text" name="pre_ref_position[]" id="pre_ref_position">
```

**Form post with ajax and return data like this;**

```
[
    0:{pre_ref_position:'example1'}
    1:{pre_ref_position:'example2'}
]
```

So I want to save this data with eloquent but how can I handle this array and save each row in the database?

Comment: Can you post your controller method that receives the post? You probably just need to iterate the request input. If you post it here, I can write it for you.

Comment: No controller yet i'm trying, but i'm using like that; $newRef = $request->ref_data
And this 'ref_data' an array.

Comment: nobody can answer without knowing the relations that you set up

Comment: there is no relation or any controller @shigg this is just question. If you have an array like this, how you save db with eloquent.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you receive your array in a variable called `$refVal`in your controller

Then use the following code:

```
$refArr = [];
foreach($refVal as $key => $val)
{
  $now = Carbon::now();
  //ref_pos in the array below refers to the field name in your database.
  $refArr[] = [ 'ref_pos' => $val['pre_ref_position'] ,'created_at' => $now, 'updated_at' => $now ];
}


//assuming model name is `Position`
Position::insert($refArr);
```